# PageMethod failure over 90% of the time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have a this WebMethod:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if a User Name is valid
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="UserName"></param>
    /// <param name="UserPassword"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [WebMethod]
    public static Object LogUser(String UserName, String UserPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            return new BLL.LogIn().LogUser(UserName, UserPassword);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

That is called in this .js

```
function LogUser() {

var UserName = document.getElementById('txt_usr').value;
var UserPassword = document.getElementById('txt_pass').value;


// Validations
if (UserName == "")
{
    alert("Falta informar el nombre del Usuario");
    return;
}

if (UserPassword == "") {
    alert("Falta informar el password del Usuario");
    return;
}

PageMethods.LogUser(UserName, UserPassword, onSucess, onError);

function onSucess(result) {
    if (result == false) {
        alert("El Usuario o Contraseña incorrecto");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("true");
        windows.location.href = 'List.aspx';
    }
    alert('Sucess');
}
function onError(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.get_message() + "; " +
    "Stack Trace: " + error.get_stackTrace() + "; " +
    "Status Code: " + error.get_statusCode() + "; " +
    "Exception Type: " + error.get_exceptionType() + "; " +
    "Timed Out: " + error.get_timedOut());
    windows.location.href = 'errorManipulation.aspx';
}
```

}

With this Web.Config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web></configuration>
```

The problem that I'm getting is that 90% of the time, the return get in the OnError, but when I debug the data, in the WebMethod the function go OK.

This is the error:

```
Error on the server method 'logUser' ; Stack Trace; Status Code: 0; Exeption Type:; Timed Out: false
```

Some one have a Idea what can be causing this?

Comment: did you add the EnablePageMethods="true" in the ScriptManager? Also, did you mean that the call correctly hit and return the object in the server side but is hitting the onError function in the client side?